# excel VBA filter pivot table with flexible names

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

```
Set Weight_wb = Application.Workbooks(WEIGHTFileName).Sheets("TERRY_CAT")
Set pt = Weight_wb .PivotTables("PivotTable4")


With Weight_wb .PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Cat")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With Weight_wb .PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Cat")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    On Error Resume Next
    .PivotItems("black").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("yellow").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("brown").Visible = False
    .Position = 1
End With
```

I want to change the above code to be more flexible.
I want to write a more general sub SetClolumnFilter, so that I can simply call:

```
SetColumnFilter WEIGHTFileName, "Terry_cat", "PivotTable4", "CAT","black"
```

something like (it doesnt work):

```
Sub SetPageFilter(WB As String, WS As String, pt As String, fd As String,value as string)
Dim wb_ As Workbook, ws_ As Worksheet, pt_ As PivotTable, fd_ As PivotField

ws_ = Application.Workbooks(WB).Sheets(WS)
pt_ = ws_.PivotTables(pt)
fd_ = pt_.PivotFields(fd)
With fd_
.Orientation = xlPageField
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim i As Long

        .PivotItems(1).Visible = True
        For i = 2 To Field.PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i).Name = Value Then _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = True Else _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a helpful description of the problem.  How does it not work?  Does it give an error?  If so, which line?  If no error, how does the code not produce the result you are looking for?  One thing to be aware of is that you must have at least one visible item in the set of `PivotItems`.  This is always tricky when you iterate them because it is not necessarily known which ones are hidden/visible.  You can force them all visible first and then run your code to hide them all but one if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SetPageFilter(WB As String, WS As String, pt As String, fd As String,value as string)
Dim wb_ As Workbook, ws_ As Worksheet, pt_ As PivotTable, fd_ As PivotField

ws_ = Application.Workbooks(WB).Sheets(WS)
pt_ = ws_.PivotTables(pt)
fd_ = pt_.PivotFields(fd)
With fd_
    .Orientation = xlPageField
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim i As Long

    With fd_
        .PivotItems(.PivotItems.Count).Visible = True
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i).Name = Value Then _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = True Else _
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```